# Is it possible to have different logger paths per cucumber features or scenarios?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, logs

So I'm using selenium with cucumber and right now and run my tests sequentially, at the end of the execution I collect the log and the prints. 
My question is, once I start executing them in parallel, how do I separate the execution logs?
I know that I can copy the prints to a specific folder that follows the scenario name and that works great, but I was wishing I could separate the logs during the execution too, so I could use them as evidence, it often can hold valuable information.

What is the best practice on collecting evidence during parallel execution?
I've looked for it in the Internet but no luck.

Thanks in advance!